# Spree/Solidus - Custom.css isn't taking precedent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I’ve created a custom.css in assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend to host my custom css, however it seems that it isn’t taking precedent over other styles that are already set in solidus.
For example i’m selecting .price and i am trying to change the product listing price text colour to red for example, but it won’t change whatsoever even when i change it in custom.css. The selector is completely fine i’m sure.
I’m using a fresh install too.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe problem `scaffolds.scss`, delete your `scaffolds.scss` & then see result

Comment: @ShabbirAhmed I don't have a scaffolds.scss. However when i added !important; after the css it worked. Does this mean that my custom.css stylesheet isn't taking precedent over the other stylesheets? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Load order is important, not really sure how "other styles that are already set in solidus" are getting loaded but, use the code! look at:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/3-0-stable/frontend/app/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend.css

You can add your own frontend.css file to specify the order that all your css gets loaded. `require_tree .` of course loads files in alphabetical order. You might need to change the order of other CSS files, depending on your environment and expectations.